# How to separate batch args by comma?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to write a batch that receive args and runs something like:

```
runmyexe.batch
==============    
myexe.exe %1, %2, %3
```

Each of my args is surrounded by quotes (because it is a path to a file that might contain spaces, like `C:\Program Files\foo.txt`).
The problem is that the number of args is unknown.
How can I still run `myexe.exe` with all the given pathes separated by comma?

Thanks.

Comment: I read `.exe`, how is this a batch?

Comment: It is a batch file that runs an exe file (the batch does other irrelevant things too)

Comment: I think you are making something up, or leaving out information in your question. But command-line arguments doesn't work the way you want to do it: `a.exe %1, %2`.

Comment: You really got me. I am a little shady and decided making up things on stackoverflow for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying it from [here](http://www.hccp.org/bat-cmd-line-args.html), you will comma-separate all your arguments this way:

```
set ALL_ARGS=
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set ALL_ARGS=%1%
shift
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set ALL_ARGS=%ALL_ARGS%, %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Build up argument string using delayed expansion.
REM See the following commands for further enlightenment:
REM   SETLOCAL /?
REM   FOR /?
REM   SET /?
REM   CALL /?
SET args=
FOR %%p IN (%*) DO (
    IF "!args!" EQU "" (
        SET args=%%p
    ) ELSE (
        SET args=!args!, %%p
    )
    REM ECHO %%p
)
ECHO myexe.exe %args%
:: CALL myexe.exe %args%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a rather specific solution. It can only be used if *all* arguments are guaranteed to be quoted and they are always spaced on the command line by exactly one space.

The idea is to store the entire set of arguments (`%*`) into a variable and replace every occurrence of `" "` (which would denote a space between the arguments) with `", "`, like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET args=%*
SET args=%args:" "=", "%
myexe.exe %args%
```

To account for certain special symbols, you might also want to use delayed expansion:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET args=%*
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET args=!args:" "=", "!
myexe.exe !args!
```